# How to Divide Control Class into Implementation vs. Public Interface?

Tags: c++, mfc, controls

I've created an MFC control class, which I derived from CWnd.

The control is written from scratch and does not use any child controls. This single class implements all the control logic, including state maintenance, painting, responding to events, etc.

In addition, I need a more "public" interface to be used by the code that uses the control. Ideally, it seems like this would be a simpler class with a much simpler interface. However, having two MFC classes associated with the same Window seems to cause all sorts of problems, or is not even possible.

I'm not really sure the best way to approach this. I'm interested in thoughts on how best to provide a simple interface class to a control like this.

Note that the control is not precompiled into a library or anything. It will be compiled as part of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try splitting the class in two, with the more complicated implementation class being a child of the public class.

Ordinarily I'd suggest making a separate pure virtual interface class and using multiple inheritance to connect it to MFC, but I'm guessing you'll want to be able to use the standard CWnd methods on the interface.

Comment: I kind of like the sound of that. I could create a class something like CControl that could be used to interface with the control, and then something like CControlInternal that derives from CControl that adds the core functionality. Both could reference the same window just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The MFC interfaces are simple because they don't actually implement the class, they just wrap the public API (C & WM) to make your coding easier in C++.

For instance you could `sendMessage hwnd WM_SetText` to the edit field, or use `CEdit(hwnd).setText()` to do the same.

2 Classes is the go I think, 
You could make the interface class the parent of the implementation, or perhaps go for a PIMPL model to join the interface with the implementation.

Comment: Right, MFC window classes don't implement the class, but in my case they would--that's the problem. I think the class/subclass approach would probably work okay. Thanks.